# Has human skin pigmentation adaptation and evolution ceased?

Tags: evolution, pigmentation

Before asking this question read

- [Why human skin colour disprove natural selection?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/41720/why-human-skin-colour-disprove-natural-selection)
- [Does darker skin color make it easier to live under sun?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8128/does-darker-skin-color-make-it-easier-to-live-under-sun)

though neither posed the same question or provide the answer to the present question.

In [Modern Human Diversity - Skin Color](http://humanorigins.si.edu/evidence/genetics/human-skin-color-variation/modern-human-diversity-skin-color) published by The Smithsonian National Museum of Natural History the document in pertinent part states

> As early humans moved into hot, open environments in search of food
>   and water, one big challenge was keeping cool. The adaptation that was
>   favored involved an increase in the number of sweat glands on the skin
>   while at the same time reducing the amount of body hair. With less
>   hair, perspiration could evaporate more easily and cool the body more
>   efficiently. But this less-hairy skin was a problem because it was
>   exposed to a very strong sun, especially in lands near the equator.
>   Since strong sun exposure damages the body, the solution was to evolve
>   skin that was permanently dark so as to protect against the sun’s more
>   damaging rays.
>
> ...
>
> The darker skin of peoples who lived closer to the equator was
>   important in preventing folate deficiency. Measures of skin
>   reflectance, a way to quantify skin color by measuring the amount of
>   light it reflects, in people around the world support this idea. While
>   UV rays can cause skin cancer, because skin cancer usually affects
>   people after they have had children, it likely had little effect on
>   the evolution of skin color because evolution favors changes that
>   improve reproductive success.
>
> There is also a third factor which affects skin color: coastal peoples
>   who eat diets rich in seafood enjoy this alternate source of vitamin
>   D. That means that some Arctic peoples, such as native peoples of
>   Alaska and Canada, can afford to remain dark-skinned even in low UV
>   areas. In the summer they get high levels of UV rays reflected from
>   the surface of snow and ice, and their dark skin protects them from
>   this reflected light.

Cases: Lighter skinned populations who migrated to tropical regions (for example, Mennonites in Belize, Boers in South Africa, Belgians in Congo (DRC)) and darker skinned populations which migrated to non-tropical regions (for example Africans in Britain, Africans in the northern U.S. States and Alaska, and Africans in Canada), where the diets of the populations take on the diets which in part led to the specific pigmentation, and the sun applies the same amount of light (UV; other spectrums) to the population as the population where darker or lighter skin adapted, or evolved.

Given the parameters provided, a lay person might conclude that they should be able to migrate to a specific tropic or non-tropic region of the world, take on the diet which led to the melanin production and skin pigmentation which the article states influences adaption or evolution, and over N fixed generations, or an unknown period of time, though eventually, their skin pigmentation will adapt or evolve to the population planners' desired pigmentation; that melanin production and skin pigmentation is not fixed, that evolution and adaptation as to skin pigmentation is continuously ongoing in the human population on Earth circa 2019 CE - and the claim is capable of being reproduced, observed and objectively measured using the scientific method.

Have any scientific studies been performed which substantiates or refutes by observable measurement the theory or claim that environment and diet have an effect on melanin production and skin pigmentation within the scope of any timescale (["One generation, two generations, ten generations, 10-20 generations"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/81319/has-human-skin-pigmentation-adaptation-and-evolution-ceased?noredirect=1#comment144723_81319))?

Comment: I downvoted because this question, despite its length, seems to strongly misunderstand evolution and because I suspect it is not asked in good faith. See a good reference on basic evolution like https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/home.php

Comment: @BryanKrause Gather what evolution and adaptation are. Have no "faith" in anything. The question asks for facts: have any studies been performed to substantiate the claim presented as to melanin production and diet having measurable impact and influence over skin pigmentation; which obviously can be proven true and correct or false by examining the cases provided as example at the question.

Comment: "In good faith" is a phrase not related to the typical meaning of "faith" as religious belief. Saying I don't think your question is in good faith means I think you're probably asking it because you want to infer something about race, rather than having any actual interest in human evolution.

Comment: The claim is that melanin production may have been selected against in higher latitudes and selected for in lower latitudes. The evidence is that populations near the equator tend to have darker skin than those far from the equator, across multiple continents.

Comment: @BryanKrause Am fully aware that "race" has absolutely no basis in science and "it is a made-up label", etc. Do not self-identify with any fictitious "race". Am asking about the actual science. Yes, have an interest in evolution, though am not compelled to agree with every assertion made under the banner of evolution or adaptation. _"The evidence is that populations near the equator tend to have darker skin than those far from the equator, across multiple continents."_ Is that true for Mennonites in Belize?  The question is: Is that process ongoing _right now_?

Comment: @BryanKrause Just re-read your comment and noticed the _"may have been"_ ("used to say that something is possible or probable" http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/comparing-may-and-might). Does that intend to relegate the theory of human skin pigmentation adaptation and evolution proffered at the linked publication as just that: Merely a theory that has not been proven by way of the scientific method?

Comment: @guest271314 Are you asking whether, *today*, people with lighter skin have a lower fitness in areas where the solar radiation than people with darker skin (and similar questions for other UV and diet environments)?

Comment: Most evolution pressure has been divided by 10, maybe 50 recently due to medicine and life conveniences. good sunguards and no need to spend days out finding food makes white people able to live in the tropics, who have a max sun time of 1 hour, and very dark people can live without much sun thanks to vitamine D. Same goes for most other wild traits.

Comment: The originally linked page contains a bibliography: http://humanorigins.si.edu/evidence/genetics/human-skin-color-variation/bibliography

Comment: @Remi.b The question is clear. Am asking if the claim is measurable _right now_. If the claim of skin pigmentation being the result of diet, tropical or non-tropical residence is true and correct then the Mennonites in Belize and Dutch in Congo (DRC) and Boers in South Africa must be adapting and evolving darker skin _in real-time, right now_, and that adaptation must be observable and measurable. Similarly, the dark skinned people who migrated to Nordic countries, or Minnesota, Alaska, Canada, and so forth _must_ be adapting and evolving lighter skin. If false, neither is measurable right now

Comment: @tsttst Which link in the bibliography provides a study which presents evidence that skin pigmentation adaptation and evolution is occurring _right now_?

Comment: You keep repeating “in real time, right now” which is at the best vague, and at the worst nonsense. “Real time” is a computing expression generally taken to mean “in a period of time that would not entail an unacceptable wait for the user”. “Right now” suggests today or even within the hour. Until you replace this by something more precise — e. g. 10-20 generations — I shall have to vote to close your question as unclear.

Comment: @David The question is clear. The conjecture that you are contriving does not make the question unclear. Yes, real-time in the computational manner that you gathered as a reference. Yes, "right now" does means today and tomorrow. Again if the claim is true that measurement must be possible, today, particularly as to the cases cited at the question. If in fact the claim is true even from one second to the next the claim must be measurable 10-20 generations are not necessary. The actual question asks if _any_ studies have been performed which publish evidence to substantiate or refute the claim.

Comment: Pardon me, but “right now” and “in real time” qualify the studies you ask about in the question in your last sentence. This is not clear and would take little effort to clarify, assuming you are clear yourself about the timescale. Are you?

Comment: @David A cursory definition of "adaptation" _"a change or the process of change by which an organism or species becomes better suited to its environment."_ Any timescale must be capable of being applied to the subject matter. If in fact the claim is measurable, from one second or one year to the next. Are Mennonites in Belize becoming darker and Africans in Scandinavia becoming lighter second by second, year by year, decade by decade, generation by generation? What terminology do you suggest to overcome what you interpret as being unclear _to you_ about the terms "right now" and "real time"?

Comment: I told you. One generation, two generations, ten generations, 10-20 generations. You choose, it's your question. Evolution questions actually bore me, and I just check them for trolls to see if they need a close vote. In your case the question was so long I looked to the end to see if there was an actual question there. There was, but the "right now in real time" stuck out like a sore thumb. Comments on SE Biology are not for discussion but for asking for clarification or suggesting improvements in a question, and that is what I did. Take my advice or leave it, but that's enough.

Comment: @David Updated the question. Does that satisfy the criteria for substitution of "right now in real time"? Used your own suggestions. Am asking if any scientific study has vetted the claim by way of empirical evidence. If the theory was true in some arbitrary period of the past the theory must be true from that arbitrary past date through to and including 2019 CE, and must be true for any moment in time that a scientist decides to capture the raw data to vet using the scientific method.